# Golang: how to proper handle dynamic select query

Tags: mysql, sql, go, dynamic

what's the best way to handle the result of a select sql query in go?

Context(thats what i got so far...):

@Update

```
func (s *SQLServiceServer) select_query_func() {
    
    // db_connection and validation

    rows, err1 := db.Query(request.GetQuery())

    if err1 != nil {
        panic(err1)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    columns, err2 := rows.Columns()

    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }

    // Loop through rows, using Scan to assign column data to struct fields.
    for rows.Next() {
        values := make([]interface{}, len(columns))

        for i := range values {
            values[i] = new(interface{})
        }
        if err2 = rows.Scan(values...); err2 != nil {
            panic(err2)
        }

        for i := range values {
            fmt.Println(values[i])
        }
    }

    return requestOutput(REQUEST_OK, RESULT_OK, ERROR_NULL)
}
```

To sumarize, what's the best approach to do it?

The error that i mentioned

[image: error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Scan`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.18#Rows.Scan) requires *allocated*, i.e. non-nil, pointers as arguments. The following types are allowed:

> ```
> *string
> *[]byte
> *int, *int8, *int16, *int32, *int64
> *uint, *uint8, *uint16, *uint32, *uint64
> *bool
> *float32, *float64
> *interface{}
> *RawBytes
> *Rows (cursor value) any type implementing Scanner (see Scanner docs)
> ```

So to fix your code you need to populate the `values` slice with non-nil pointers, and for your purpose those pointers can be of type `*interface{}`.

```golang
for rows.Next() {
    values := make([]interface{}, len(columns))
    for i := range values {
        values[i] = new(interface{})
    }
    if err := rows.Scan(values...); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: i still having the same problem, i understood the pointer to scan have to be non-nil however i can't scan in that way. I mean, i can't do this: rows.Scan(values...) theres the error on it. I tried just using rows.Scan(values) but doenst worked as well... (I'm a complete noob on golang btw) @mkopriva

Comment: @Lucosa I've tried it on my machine and it works just fine, without issues. You have to use `rows.Scan(values...)`, without the `...` it *will* fail. Please update the question by including the new code so I can take a look if you're doing it correctly. And also include the *exact* error message.

Comment: @Lucosa https://imgur.com/uxWyBgo

Comment: i just changed it :], btw im using "go-sql-driver/mysql" as driver, idk if theres something with it... @mkopriva

Comment: @Lucosa This looks like an IDE issue. Try running the code from the terminal with `go build -o ./main && ./main` and see if that passes compilation.

Comment: @Lucosa I now realise that my original answer addresses a different problem in your code. The error the IDE is showing is a compile-time error. The error that the answer addresses is a runtime-error. You still need the solution in the answer, but it's not related to the error in your question. Sorry.